# How to query in DocumentDB based on inner json object value?

Tags: c#, json, get, azure-cosmosdb

Suppose I have 3 objects in DocumentDB like this.

This is the class record.

And now I want to get all the Id's where a student exist with name sunny.

```
{
  "id": "111",
  "class": 1,
  "students": [
    {
      "name": "sunny"
    },
    {
      "name": "pinki"
    },
    {
      "name": "bobby"
    },
    {
      "name": "lucky"
    }
  ]
}

{
  "id": "222",
  "class": 2,
  "students": [
    {
      "name": "pinki"
    },
    {
      "name": "sunny"
    },
    {
      "name": "bobby"
    }
  ]
}

{
  "id": "333",
  "class": 3,
  "students": [
    {
      "name": "pinki"
    },
    {
      "name": "lucky"
    },
    {
      "name": "bobby"
    }
  ]
}
```

What will be the query to get the result?

Comment: Please take care to format your code **before** you post your question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use DocumentDB's `JOIN` to create a cross product on documents with array elements.

For example, the following query creates a cross-product on documents with it's  `students` property to query on the `students.name`:

```
select doc.id
from doc
join students in doc.students
where students.name = 'sunny'
```

returns the following dataset:

```
[{
    id: 111
}, {
    id: 222
}]
```

Reference: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-sql-query/#joins

Comment: Satish, You might want to take a look at the [Query Playground for DocumentDB](http://www.documentdb.com/sql/demo), it provides sample queries to run against predefined data and might be useful if you have similar questions in the future.